# How to print name of object that is using constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I am looking for a way to print the name of the variable on which an instance's constructor is being invoked, from inside the constructor:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() {
       std::cout << "variable name = " /*magic here*/ << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    A abc;  // should output "variable name = abc"
    A def;  // should output "variable name = def"
}
```

Is this possible and how?

Comment: the back-tick is used for in-line code, use only 4 space leading indent for blocks of code.

Comment: This question is very poorly worded. We don't know what you mean. Provide examples, in code, of what you mean. We don't know what you mean by `cout<<[object]`.

Comment: probably `cout<<this;`?

Comment: Modify your question and write a complete example of what you want with desired output.

Comment: What high-level problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Do you mean you want to print the name of the variable that is used to refer to the object? For example, if I declare an object like this: `temp x;`, you would want `"x"` to be printed in the constructor? Not possible. Also note that not all objects are associated with variables.

Comment: Please [read about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Your question is a prime example of it. And really, please show what output you would expect.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley ... that it was I exactly want...

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ... i dont want the name of derived class...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ... cant exactly tell what actual problem i am solving, like i aint allowed to do so...but u can understand  it by a simple thing...lets say...like this thing might also help me show my students that the order of calling of constructor and that of destructor is in reverse order

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ... just read the XY problem on the link u gave...good thing but i m afraid that is not the scene over here...i want x and i m asking for x only...well still thanks got something new not if the answer then...

Comment: But *why* do you want to "get the name"? The only thing we can tell you right now is that it's impossible. But if you tell us *why* you want then name, what the *actual* problem is that you try to solve, instead of just telling us your solution to this unknown problem and asking us to help you with that, then maybe we can help you find *another* solution, one that isn't impossible. That's what the XY problem is, someone telling us a solution to an unknown problem, and asking us help with some problems with the solution. Without knowing the problem those questions are hard or impossible.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ... firstly thank you so much for taking time into looking into this problem... secondly i have signed an N.D.A. , so i cant open up a little more than this...but i would like that this question is kept opened so that ifsomeday someone will get this impossible ting possible...than perhaps thatday

Comment: @ShreyanMehta So if you signed an NDA, why even ask the initial question?  In any event, I doubt you need an NDA to say something like "I'm trying to call a function, given its name" or "I'm doing a name lookup" or "I'm writing a tool and need to get compile-time information" or something similar to that.  It isn't as if we're going to get trade secrets from you if you asked the question in this way.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ... its not about you... its about me... by mistake i might tell things which might put me in trouble... putting question like this wont put me in trouble but if i go further than i might end up in trouble...

Comment: This is not possible, you would have to change the code to `A abc("abc");`.  This could involve a macro , e.g. `#define DEFINE_A(name) A name(#name)`

Comment: @ShreyanMehta Your inability to figure out how to construct a representative example of your real problem is a red flag that you may be in over your head on whatever this job is, and in good faith you may wish to consider advising your employer to hire additional experienced help. That said, I have voted to reopen the question as Benjamin W.'s edit has at least clarified it.

Comment: @JasonC thanks for reopening the question... and your this suggestion i have worked upon... i have demanded a senior person...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to do that without using macros.

If your class had a constructor taking a const char* then you could use a fake constructor macro to pass the variable name into the real constructor. I'm not sure why you'd want to do that though and this is a pretty ugly solution.

`#define CONSTRUCT(type, name) type name(#name)`